# How to return multiple rows from Multiple XML nodes Combine with SQL Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to combine XML and data from tables of SQL Server. I am trying to do so and facing following error.

> ***Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
> Incorrect syntax near 'response'.***

XML...

```
set @sqlxml = N'<response xmlns="http://xyz.in/twa/cmm/decl/v2">
<identification>88762431</identification>
<type>RESPONSE</type>
<submitter><identifier>40134916C</identifier></submitter>
<functionalReference>TSW07389555IM1</functionalReference>
<transactionType>24</transactionType>
<attachDocument>
    <category>AAA</category>
    <mimeCode>application/pdf</mimeCode>
    <URI>16f15574-5d5a-4e83-b9ac-2151f10cf2eb</URI>
    <filename>XYZ_B2021_199.pdf</filename>
</attachDocument>
<attachDocument>
    <category>AAB</category>
    <mimeCode>text/plain</mimeCode>
    <URI>1511b476-a2be-4ae5-a54c-0a5dc14759b2</URI>
    <filename>XYZ_B2021_199_xml.txt</filename>
</attachDocument>
<additionalInformationICN><text>Please refer to attached XYZ for Directions</text></additionalInformationICN>
<issueDate>20210331113355</issueDate>
<overallDeclaration>
    <identification>88762431</identification>
    <functionalReference>TSW07389555IM1</functionalReference>
    <submitter>
        <identifier>40134916C</identifier>
    </submitter>
    <responsibleGovernmentAgency>XYZ</responsibleGovernmentAgency>
</overallDeclaration>
<status>
    <agency>XYZ</agency>
    <effectiveDate>20210331113355</effectiveDate>
    <name>B04</name>
    <releaseDate>20210331113355</releaseDate>
</status>
</response>'
```

SQL Script...

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://xyz.in/twa/cmm/decl/v2' AS ns)
SELECT distinct lv.[VERSION] LocationVersion,
lv.CHANGE_REASON LocationVersionChangeReason,
lv.CREATED_TIMESTAMP LocationVersionCreatedTimestamp,
lrd.CATEGORY,
lrd.MIME_TYPE as mimecode,
coalesce(lrd.[OBJECT_ID], lrd.FILENET_ID) as URI,
lrd.DOCUMENT_NAME as [FileName],
cast(lrd.SEQUENCE as bigint) sequence
response.value('(/response/status/agency/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as ResponseAgency,
response.value('(/response/issueDate/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as ResponseIssueDateTime,
response.value('(/response/additionalInformationICN/text/text())[1]','varchar(1000)') as ResponseClearanceInstructions
FROM DB.Location l
INNER JOIN DB.Location_RESPONSE lr ON l.Location_ENTITY_KEY = lr.Location_ENTITY_KEY
INNER JOIN DB.Location_RESPONSE_DOCUMENT lrd ON lr.Location_RESPONSE_KEY = lrd.Location_RESPONSE_KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.Location_VERSION lv on lr.Location_VERSION_KEY = lv.Location_VERSION_KEY
INNER JOIN DB.Location_RESPONSE lr2 on l.Location_ENTITY_KEY = lr2.Location_ENTITY_KEY
CROSS APPLY @sqlxml.nodes('/response') AS xmltable(response)
WHERE l.Llocation_ENTITY_KEY = 123456789
```

Sql script is working fine return data from database without including XML as below...

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://xyz.in/twa/cmm/decl/v2' AS ns)
SELECT distinct lv.[VERSION] LocationVersion,
lv.CHANGE_REASON LocationVersionChangeReason,
lv.CREATED_TIMESTAMP LocationVersionCreatedTimestamp,
lrd.Category,
lrd.MIME_TYPE as Mimecode,
coalesce(lrd.[OBJECT_ID], lrd.FILENET_ID) as URI,
lrd.DOCUMENT_NAME as [FileName],
cast(lrd.SEQUENCE as bigint) [Sequence]
--response.value('(/response/status/agency/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as ResponseAgency,
--response.value('(/response/issueDate/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as ResponseIssueDateTime,
--response.value('(/response/additionalInformationICN/text/text())[1]','varchar(1000)') as ResponseClearanceInstructions
FROM DB.Location l
INNER JOIN DB.Location_RESPONSE lr ON l.Location_ENTITY_KEY = lr.Location_ENTITY_KEY
INNER JOIN DB.Location_RESPONSE_DOCUMENT lrd ON lr.Location_RESPONSE_KEY = lrd.Location_RESPONSE_KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.Location_VERSION lv on lr.Location_VERSION_KEY = lv.Location_VERSION_KEY
INNER JOIN DB.Location_RESPONSE lr2 on l.Location_ENTITY_KEY = lr2.Location_ENTITY_KEY
--CROSS APPLY @sqlxml.nodes('/response') AS xmltable(response)
WHERE l.Llocation_ENTITY_KEY = 123456789
```

Result...
[image]

Can someone help pls?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You forgot your comma at the end of the line cast(lrd.SEQUENCE as bigint) sequence

Comment: As Larnu is often fond of saying... `;` is a statement terminator, not a statement beginninator. It's bad form to have `;WITH` anything.

Comment: Try using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://xyz.in/twa/cmm/decl/v2')` instead.

Comment: Also try removing `/response/` from your `response.value()` XPaths ... `@sqlxml.nodes()` has already selected the `/response` element so `/response/...` is redundant.

Comment: Unclear why you have `.nodes` there at all, there is only one `<response>` node

Comment: Thanks everyone for your assistant...

Comment: @) Bee_Riii  and @ AlwaysLearning  – I learned from article  **[manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server/)**

Comment: Just another issue... Query returning only one row first one... should be 2 rows as per two nodes of "attachDocument". Pls advise what I am missing here that preventing from returning 2 rows for both nodes  of "attachDocument"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing with XML is called shredding. It converts XML data type into a rectangular/relational format. After that you need to **join** it with the rest of data in some other DB tables.

The easiest way to achieve it is via CTE. And you need to join data/columns from the resultset **rs.*** with the rest of the DB tables.

Along the following:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://xyz.in/twa/cmm/decl/v2'), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('(category/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') as Category,
        c.value('(mimeCode/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') as MimeCode,
        c.value('(URI/text())[1]','UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') as URI,
        c.value('(filename/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') as [FileName],
        c.value('(/response/status/agency/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') as ResponseAgency,
        c.value('(/response/issueDate/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') as ResponseIssueDateTime,
        c.value('(/response/additionalInformationICN/text/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') as ResponseClearanceInstructions
   FROM @sqlxml.nodes('/response/attachDocument') AS t(c)
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs INNER JOIN ...;
```

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak.. are you able to refer any good article... would be helpful (or an example will help with thought around it).

Comment: @SQLHoncho, please connect with me on LinkedIn. We will have a chat on the subject.

Comment: Done and with you :)